# How to use lambda expressions and predicates with Entity Framework

Tags: generics, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, extension-methods

I am new to using lambda-expressions with Entity Framework and will appreciate some help in this regard.

In my project, I have two entities **Author** and **Course** with 1-M relationship (an Author can have multiple Courses):

```
public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses {get; set;}
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}

    public int AuthorId {get; set;}
    public virtual Author {get; set;}
}
```

I want to retrieve all Authors with associated Courses - **the same applies to other entities in my project**. For this reason, I want a Get() method similar to the following:

```
public class GenericService<T> where T : class
{
    // DbContext defined

    public IEnumerable<T> Get(...) 
    { 
        return Context...
    }
}
```

In my controller action, I would do something similar to the following:

```
    public ActionResult Get_Authors_With_Courses ()
    {
        // var authors = Get (...)
        return View(authors);
    }
```

I am not sure how to define the **Get(...)** method which returns the parent/child objects. Can someone guide me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is simple linq,

```
context.Authors.Include(A => A.Courses).ToList();
```

this will return all your Authors with their Courses.

if you want a generic one,

```
public class GenericService<T> where T : class
{
    // DbContext defined = db

    public IEnumerable<T> Get(string pathtoinclude  = "") 
    { 
       // add checking if path is null remove the Include extension 
       // path to include in your example is courses 
        return  db.Set<T>().Include(pathtoinclude).AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

you can use it like this

```
var authors = Get<Author>("Courses");
```

Comment: Munzer, that worked like a charm. This is what I was looking for especially the generic part. Is there a way to load all Child objects in one go? I think for such case, we have to write separate queries.

Comment: I think a better practice would be enabling Lazy Loading [read this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx), this way should work.

Comment: I am glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all Authors that have one or more associated courses then you need

```
var authorsWithCourses = context.Authors.Where(a => a.Courses.Any()).ToList();
```

If you want to also return the Courses the you could use Include

```
var authorsWithCourses = context.Authors
    .Include(a => a.Courses)
    .Where(a => a.Courses.Any())
    .ToList();
```

Although I prefer projection over Include usually so you could do something like

```
var authorsWithCourses = context.Authors
    .Where(a => a.Courses.Any())
    .Select(a => new {
        Author=a.Name, 
        Courses = a.Courses.Select(c => c.Title)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Phil, I like the idea of projection. This helps customize the output.